# Scala trait or concrete class

Tags: scala, class, traits

So I get what we can do with traits but in what cases should we prefer their use to a concrete class ? I was told to use traits everywhere I can and when I need to instanciate something use a regular class.

Edit : I am actually asking about when to use a trait insted of a concrete class not an abstract one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's often the case, there is no single rule, but I personally found useful a general suggestion give in Odersky/Spoon/Venners book "Programming in Scala".

It says if the behaviour will not be reused in other unrelated classes, use a concrete class. On the other hand, if you think you'll reuse that behaviour somewhere else in unrelated places, make it a trait.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted !

Comment: Sorry, but an external link without at least a summary isn't ideal (in this case specifically I get a "viewing limit" message for that page).

Comment: @TravisBrown I edited the question, mine was actually different and mfirry provided the exact answer to it.